# Targeting last form field in form and then some

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this form where I'm trying to target a certain element which doesn't have its own class. Unfortunately, I can't change the html.

I'm trying to target the last `.formfield` element and then the second `p` tag after that.

i've tried with `:last-child`, `:last-of-type` and :`nth-last-child()` but I can't seem to get the last one.

with the html below, how can I target the `<p>Target me</p>`?

```css
.form form[name="pageform"] .formfield:last-child+p+p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form enctype="" name="pageform" onsubmit="formhandler(); return true;" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1">
    <div class="formfield">...
    </div>
    <div class="formfield">...
    </div>
    <div class="formfield">...
    </div>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="gdpr-accept"></p>
    <p>Target me</p>
    <div id="submit_div">
      <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Send">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot target *last class*. You could use something based on the order of HTML elements e.g.:

```
.formfield + p + p { }
```

Or this:

```
div:nth-last-of-type(2) + p + p { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
form[name="pageform"] p:last-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jqnx9fh6/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS specifity:

```
div.form form p:last-of-type {
    background: red;
}
```